# Requirement status not updating when the linkage is created via test importer

Tags: jira-xray

In Xray test management and within a Jira environment, the requirement status of the story is not changing to `(not Run)` when I linked it within a test from the test importer (using a CSV).

Is it a bug? If I do the same manually, the requirement status is changing.

Does anyone have a solution for this?

CSV like:
[image]

Map of coverage:
[image]

Comment: Can you please the a sample of the CSV you've used?

Comment: Hi Sérgio, I didn't get your question you want me to share the CSV, right?

Comment: Yep, sorry it was a typo :) If you can share the CSV related to that test and also a screenshot of your story it would be great

Comment: It is just a dummy CSV that I've tested with I put a snap above. The story I can't share, unfortunately.

Comment: Can you please share a screenshot of the mapping you did in the Test Case Importer wizard? How did you map the "Coverage" column?

Comment: Sure, I've mapped the "Coverage" column to Link "Tests". I'll add it to the description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to replicate this issue in Xray cloud and it works fine; since it's a SaaS solution, it should behave similar on your end. At first sight all seems to be ok. Nevertheless I'll share some instructions that may be helpful.
Things to check in order for the coverage in a story to show as "NOTRUN", whenever we "add" a Test issue to it:

- make sure the Story is configured as being a "coverable issue type" in the project settings
- make sure you're adding the Test issue type from Xray and not another one which may have a similar name (somethimes this happens in some environments where people try other tools or create their own issue types by hand)
- whenever creating Tests and linking them to requirements/user stories by using the Test Case Importer, make sure you map the CSV column where you identify the Story issue key to the 'Link "tests" outward'
- if all the previous are ok and the problem persists, you may try to reindex the project; go to your project settings > Apps > Xray Settings > Reindex ([info](https://docs.getxray.app/display/XRAYCLOUD/Project+Settings%3A+Re-Indexing))
- if the last doesn't work, please reach out to [Xray support team](https://jira.getxray.app/servicedesk/customer/portal/2) so they can have a look it in more detail with you

Comment: I've tested it again but unfortunately, it persists from my side. regarding your first point, of course, the issue is configured as being coverable if not I couldn't notice this point from the beginning and I would not be having the requirement status on my story. regarding your second point, I wanted to mention that yes it is xRay test type I am sure about it at 99%. regarding the third point, I confirm that it links "tests" as I mentioned already in the post description above. regarding the reindexing point honestly, I haven't tried since I do not see the issue that severe and I'll wkaround

Comment: I've checked the Jira bulk change and more specifically the Reset Xray Requirement Status Custom Fields it resolves the issue and changes the requirement status to NOTRUN as expected.

Comment: So, you were using Xray on Jira server/datacenter and not Xray on Jira cloud as you mentioned on the initial post :) Glad this has been solved

Comment: I see, I'll remove it. thank you for the info.